# Java JaxB generation, How do I get a bigDecimal from my xsd?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, bigdecimal

I have an xsd annotation that I am trying to get to Marshal into a java object.  I would like the java to end up with BigDecimal for its value.  What do I enter in the xsd to make it do this?  I am using an xjc ant task

```
<xjc schema="my.xsd" destdir="generated" header="false" extension="true" />
```

Here is the relevant xsd -

```
<complexType name="Size">
    <attribute name="height" type="BigDecimal"></attribute> <!-- this is wrong-->
</complexType>
```

I would like to end up with this for the generated class -

```
public class Size { 
@XmlAttribute(name = "height")
    protected BigDecimal height;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation will generate a `java.math.BigDecimal` from the `decimal` type (see Table 6-1 in the
JAXB 2.2 specification).

**XML Schema (schema.xsd)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="foo">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="bar" type="decimal"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>

</schema>
```

**XJC Call**

```
xjc schema.xsd
```

**Java Model (Foo)**

```
package org.example.schema;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"bar"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected BigDecimal bar;

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out.  The answer is to use a binding.xjb class

binding =

```
<jxb:javaType 
     name="java.math.BigDecimal" 
     xmlType="xs:decimal"/>
```

ant -

```
<xjc schema="my.xsd" destdir="generated" binding="myBinding.xjb" header="false" extension="true" />
```

xsd =

```
<attribute name="height" type="decimal"></attribute>
```

This means anything marked as type decimal will turn into a big decimal but in my case that is ok.  Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: A JAXB implementation will create a `java.math.BigDecimal` property for the `xs:decimal` type, no binding file required:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17823855/383861

Comment: I just tested this and @BlaiseDoughan is correct.  I over-thought this one for sure.  Thanks!